# Trying to make a histogram with two variables and keep coming up with 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r

I am trying to make a good histogram with two variables, height, and free throw percent. I've​ imported the data using excel and used the hist function but keep coming up with 'x' must be numeric.

I can read the data and create a table.
I've tried hist(height$freethrow)
and hist(shortkings)

[This is what my data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6zj1.png)
[Second part of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfEke.jpg)
hist(shortkings)
Error in hist.default(shortkings) : 'x' must be numeric

> hist(shortkings, xlab = Height, ylab = Freethrow, main = Freethrow)
>   Error in hist.default(shortkings, xlab = Height, ylab = Freethrow, main = Freethrow) : 
>     'x' must be numeric

I would like to create a histogram that shows distribution.

Comment: Did you try `class(shortkings)` or `str(shortkings)` ? I suspect that it is related to how you read the data.

Comment: What do your data look like? it could be that there is a comma in the value.

Comment: I added a picture of what my data look likes. When I tried class(shortkings) i got [1] "data.frame"

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run `class(shortkings$Height)`

If you see that it's non-numeric, then you can do the following and re-run the `hist()` function

```r
shortkings$Height <- as.integer(shortkings$Height)
```